# Command to fetch pagesize in windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using `wmic /node:NODENAME memlogical get totalpagefilespace` but it does not work on all windows versions. Is there a command which works on all windows version?

**Note**: Without having to install any 3rd party pgms

Comment: What versions is that not working against?

Comment: @Jim B: OS Name Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Enterprise. (64bit) It says `memlogical - Alias not found.`

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell would do the trick:

```
gc c:\servers.txt | % {
    $server = $_
    $physicalmem = gwmi -computer $server Win32_ComputerSystem | % {$_.TotalPhysicalMemory}
    gwmi -computer $server Win32_PageFile | select `
        @{ Name = "Server" ; Expression = { $server.ToUpper() } },
        @{ Name = "PageFileLocation" ; Expression = { $_.Name } },
        @{ Name = "PageFileSize" ; Expression = { [Math]::Round($_.FileSize/1MB,0) } },
        @{ Name = "PhysicalMemory" ; Expression = { [Math]::round($physicalmem/1MB,0) } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already mentioned, I need something without using any `3rd party pgms` as this is going to be used by customers n without dependency of installing any 3rd party applications